# How to wrap some text around an image?

Tags: image, apache-flex, word-wrap

In flex, I have HBox in which I have loaded an image. I want to wrap text around it. Hence, there would be an image on right and text will be on left. After the image is cleared, text will be displayed 100% of the width.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: I am able to do it using htmlText property. But, I want to wrap text around HBox ( that contains image)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although what you describe is easy to do with HTML. I didn't think the htmlText property in Flex supported anything more than simple HTML.

You'll want to look into the [Text Layout Framework](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/textlayout/) for Flex.

---

Edit: Despite my initial claim, the htmlText property actually does support the img tag with align property.  It is documented [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_04.html)

Comment: using html, ( <image align='right'>hello text ) would work but I want to wrap text around HBox.

Comment: I'm sure HTML and Flex cannot be mixed in that way.  You should look into the Text Layout Framework to accomplish what you need.